# Exists Vs IN Vs =

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

Considering that the MASTER table has primary Key over the column ID

This is the original query

> UPDATE A SET ID = DESC WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MASTER IM2 WHERE
>   IM2.CD_ID = :B2 AND IM2.ID = A.DESC)

This is the Modified Query 1

> UPDATE A SET ID = DESC WHERE A.DESC IN (SELECT IM2.DESC FROM MASTER
>   IM2 WHERE IM2.CD_ID = :B2 AND IM2.ID = A.DESC)

This is the modified Query 2

> UPDATE A SET ID = DESC WHERE A.DESC  = (SELECT IM2.DESC FROM MASTER
>   IM2 WHERE IM2.CD_ID = :B2 AND IM2.ID = A.DESC)

- The modified Query 1 makes use of a index on the table MASTER
- The modified Query 2 makes use of the primary Key of MASTER

Both the modified ones are performing better.

Are the 3 queries functionally same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are different from the first query.
The first query is checking two conditions:

1. IM2.CD_ID = :B2
2. IM2.ID = A.DESC

while remaining two queries are checking three conditions:

1. M2.CD_ID = :B2
2. IM2.ID = A.DESC
3. A.DESC = IM2.DESC

Please take a look at conditions #2 and #3, and their implications.... 
`IM2.id = A.DESC`  and  `A.DESC = IM2.DESC` ===> `IM2.id = IM2.DESC`

So two last queries are equivalent to:

> .... WHERE EXISTS(
>    SELECT 1 FROM MASTER IM2
>  
>    WHERE IM2.CD_ID = :B2 AND IM2.ID = A.DESC **AND IM2.id = IM2.DESC**    )

Comment: Thanks. If I change to the following then are they same?

UPDATE A SET ID = DESC WHERE A.DESC IN (SELECT IM2.ID FROM MASTER IM2 WHERE IM2.CD_ID = :B2 AND IM2.ID = A.DESC)